# How to force dbo schema name?

Tags: sql-server-2005, managed, user-defined-functions

I'm using "SQL SERVER PROJECT" in VS 2008 to create UDF in C#
Then I'm using DEPLOY command to publish DLL into MS SQL server 2005

All works well except all created UDFs are owned by me (as user) 
But I wanted to keep dbo schema (eg: dbo.UDF_TEST - not jonny.UDF_TEST)

Any idea how to manage thar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found another approach allowing do everything inside VS.

I've added to project SQL script named "postdeployscript.sql":

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(200)

SET @SQL = 'alter schema dbo transfer ' + CURRENT_USER +'.[UDF_GET_AUDIT_VALUE]'

EXECUTE (@SQL)

GO

script is executed automaticcally by VS during depolyment process and changes schemas from current user to DBO.

Cons: you need to add each UDF/USP you are ceating manually

PS: Please note you can also use predeployscript.sql to execute some commmands before deployment

Comment: You don't have to add them manually - you can use something like "SELECT name FROM sysobjects where xtype='FN'" and just iterate over that to apply the changes to every function in your database.

Answer (score 1):

deploy the UDF from an account that is sysadmin, or dbo on the database.
You can build the dll and then manually deploy it  by logging into management studio as dbo to the database and running these commands:

> CREATE ASSEMBLY Geocode FROM
>
> 'C:\PATH\YourUDF.dll' WITH
>
> PERMISSION_SET = SAFE

or

1. From within Visual Studio in the
   solution explorer click on the UDF
   project (not the solution).
2. Go to properties.
3. Click on the database tab.
4. You can change the connection
   string, and also change the assembly
   owner here.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I'm forced to use AD and Windows auth.
So I cannot easy log as dbo

I'd prefrer 2nd option you have mentioned.
I've SQL Server project, then at its property I've entered "dbo" at assembly owner as adviced - unfortunatelly it didnt help

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you need to be  sysadmin on the database to be able to set objects to have dbo ownership