# How to create CLR procedure in C# that will be deployed in schema other than DBO

Tags: c#, sql, schema, clr, database-schema

I would like to create an SQL function that will be deployed in a schema other than DBO.

I found a post where a workaround with post build script is explained.

[How to force dbo schema name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639141/how-to-force-dbo-schema-name)

I could use the above mentioned solution, but i kinda feel there should be something more civilized that that. Some parameter settings maybe, or attribute.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There are two options to achieve what you want:

- you can configure the owner of the Procedure in the project settings/tab database
- otherwise the default schema of the connection you use in VS is the one getting used

So if you want it put in a different schema you either use a connection with your target schema as default schema or configure the project settings accordingly...

Comment: Unfortunatelly I wasn't able to solve the problem. The first option you mentioned did not succeed. As for the second option, could you please explain what do you mean by "default schema of the connection". I inspected the connection advanced settings, but could not find default schema parameter.

Comment: the default schema is a setting of the user you use to connect... in SQL Server Management Studfio you can configure which schemas the user can access and which schemas he owns and which is the default schema.

Comment: Unfortunately I had no luck solving this problem the above way. Thank you Yahia.